# Residue of a positive integer for each prime $p\ge 5$

Tags: nt.number-theory

I am interested in the following fact, where I have a strong computational evidence.
Let $n$ be a positive integer and let $k\in \{1,\ldots,n-1\}$ satisfying the following two properties:

1. for every $p$ with $p\le n$,we have $p\le k$,
2. for every prime $p\ge 5$, if we let $r_n$ denote the remainder of $n$ in the division by $p$ and we let $r_k$ denote the remainder of $k$ in the division by $p$, then $r_k\le r_n$.

Except for $n=9$, either there is no such $k$, or $k=n-1$.

Comment: What is k? A collection or a number?

Comment: I have corrected the text, thanks!

Comment: Are you considering $n > 2$?